# Kinematic Property of Link

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am sorry if this question has been asked, but I haven't been able to find any solution. What exactly is the Kinematic property of a link. Why is it 'false' by default (i.e. unchecked in Gazebo GUI). What is the purpose of the property. Any explanation or link to an explanation would be very helpful.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25064/kinematic-property-of-link/) by [Shrutheesh R Iyer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26374/shrutheesh-r-iyer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A kinematic link (as opposed to a dynamic link) is not affected by external forces. It can influence other bodies in its vicinity, but it's not influenced by them. You can use the kinematic property of a link to take control of the link from the physics engine. Then you get to define by yourself how the link should move in the world (for example, to create an animation). Here is a [reference](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/deps/opende/include/gazebo/ode/objects.h#L1567) to the kinematic state.

Below you can see how a box interacts with gravity and a sphere, with disabled and enabled kinematic state.

[image: kinematic-state]

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shrutheesh R Iyer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26374/shrutheesh-r-iyer/) on 2020-05-09**:
Thank you for the detailed explanation!